# How to fix a Ruby "no such file to load -- xsd/qname" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, ruby-1.9

I'm trying to run the FlightXML2 Ruby library for accessing the FlightAware API. (The library's code is here: https://github.com/flightaware/flightxml2-client-ruby)

When including the library file with the line "require 'FlightXML2.rb'", the following exception occurs:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- xsd/qname
    from /...PATH TO GEMS.../activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /...PATH TO GEMS.../activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /...PATH TO GEMS.../activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /...PATH TO GEMS.../activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /...PATH TO GEMS.../lib/FlightXML2.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /...PATH TO GEMS.../activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /...PATH TO GEMS.../activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /...PATH TO GEMS.../activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /...PATH TO GEMS.../activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from (irb):2
    from /...PATH TO GEMS.../railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /...PATH TO GEMS.../railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /...PATH TO GEMS.../railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I suspect this has to do with incompatibility between Ruby 1.9 and 1.8, for which the library was written. Is there a way to make this work with Ruby 1.9?

Answer (score 2):

In order to make FlightXML2 run in my Rails project, I had to install the 'xmlparser' and 'soap4r' gems with the following Gemfile additions:

```
gem 'xmlparser'
gem 'soap4r', :git => 'git://github.com/felipec/soap4r.git'
```

And also add the following compatibility band-aids:

```
require 'rexml/document'
require 'continuation'

class Symbol
  def sub(*args)
    to_s.sub(*args)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

what you need is

```
gem install xmlparser
gem install soap4r
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  This eliminated the above exception.  I had to add a few more things to get rid of subsequent errors, as I detail in my answer.

Comment: what things @SpaceInvader