# Out of the blue I can't start Rails server with rails -s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-18.04, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Last night I installed ruby 3.0.0 and ruby on rails 6.1.1 on my Ubuntu system by following the instructions at this link http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html and I was able to get rails running in my browser on port 3000 using command rails -s. Today I try to get it running again and I get this rails aborted error. I'm completely confounded by this issue as I did not change any settings from last night when it was working perfectly fine. I've seen other questions asked with similar issues but not with my specific error so I'm not sure how to proceed. I tried creating a separate directory and creating a new gemset for a separate project and I get the same error. Anyone have any ideas?

```
rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rexml/document
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox.rb:22:in `<main>'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/webdrivers-4.5.0/lib/webdrivers/geckodriver.rb:72:in `<main>'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/webdrivers-4.5.0/lib/webdrivers.rb:4:in `<main>'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/who/workspace/proj/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require_relative'
/home/who/workspace/proj/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `block in load'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `load'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `block in perform'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/command.rb:52:in `invoke'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/bootsnap-1.6.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/home/who/workspace/proj/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/home/who/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@proj/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/home/who/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
<internal:/home/who/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
/home/who/workspace/proj/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
<internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
/home/who/workspace/proj/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:2:in `load'
bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Few things to try before getting more into it: 1) run `bundle exec rails s` instead 2) comment out bootsnap from your Gemfile and try again 3) run `spring stop` and retry

Comment: Do you have rexml in your gemfile? It seems that it's no longer built-in.

Comment: @BroiSatse Thanks!!! Option number 1 worked: bundle exec rails s. Do you mind explaining why it works this way and do you have any idea how it's possible that rails -s worked for me last night but not today? Extremely relieved that it's working now but I'm still confused as hell. Thanks again, I was about to smash my keyboard.

Comment: @inmydelorean Which directory can I check to see if it's built-in?

Comment: @whatsinthebooox run `gem list` to see if it's installed.

Comment: @inmydelorean yes it is listed there: rexml (3.2.4)

Comment: @whatsinthebooox I guess it's fine then. But there was a change with the gem in ruby 3.0.0 so that might have caused the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13598187/9052234 @whatsinthebooox